# FullCalendar improve performance for rendering events

Tags: javascript, json, performance, fullcalendar

So far I've been using

```
.fullCalendar("renderEvent",event,true)
```

to render every event 1 by 1 and this is kinda bad performance wise, 10+ seconds load time when adding 50 events. Then I looked at a thread here on stackoverflow that suggested using

```
.fullCalendar("addEventSource", events) // events is an array of events to be added.
```

This improved the performance by a bunch but im wondering if further improvements can be made? I looked at the FullCalendar doc and found this function renderEvents (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvents/), but for me it doesn't render the events on the calendar. It was added in the newest version 3.1 so maybe it's still bugged? On paper it should be better for performance since it takes an array of events instead of having to call renderEvent for each event.

I've also optimized the code so I only make 1 ajax call to the database with all the events encoded as a single json string.

Anyone with experience on how to improve speed of rendering events?

***Edit:***

for `.fullCalendar("renderEvents",events,true)`, i put the ids of the events like this `events[i].id = _id` and the `renderEvents` call worked :) in case this becomes useful for anyone

Comment: edit a part solution for anyone interested

Comment: Also, be careful on the backend when it comes to performance which can also be a bottleneck in most applications I encountered with Fullcalendar. This might be obvious but thought mention some people return all the data source a.k.a database fields (example 20+) back and only use 3-5 of the field from the JSON payload returned. Only return the field values consumed by the calendar will also speed up the retrieval/memory needed on the client browser of the JSON before it's consumed. Pre-formatting of the values in data values instead of stepping through events after in the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Fullcalendar "events" method, which provides a callback for passing events to fullcalendar rendering. This method is very fast and I'm using this for rendering up to 2000 events per view.

Following snippet shows the relevant code for doing this in angular 2 environment. But concept can be easily adapted to pure javascript.

```
var calendarDiv: any;
var self = this;

calendarDiv = $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('#calendar');
calendarDiv.fullCalendar({
        defaultView:    "agendaWeek",
        ...
        events: function (start: any, end:any, timezone:any, callback:any) {
            calendarDiv.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            self.reloadCalendarObjects(start, end, timezone, callback);
        },
        ...
      });

 // Fetch data from remote source (AJAX)
 reloadCalendarObjects(start, end , timezone, fcCallback)  {
    // Do your Axax here
    this.dataService.getRecords('MT_CalObjects')
        .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
           self.fillCalendar(data, fcCallback);
     });
   }

 // Evaluate fetched objects, create fullcalendar events and pass them to FullCalendar Callback)
 fillCalendar(data, fcCallBack) {
    this.fcevents = [];
    for (let entry of data) {
                     this.fcevents.push({
                title: data.eventame,
                start:  data.calstartDate,
                end:    data.calendDate,
                object_id: data.id,
            });
    }
    fcCallBack(this.fcEvents);  // pass back to FullCalendar
 }
```

Comment: a bit confusing since its not js and im not too familiar with it. main problem with load time is when you drag a event to the calendar and make it recur the next year, its not when you initially try to load a page.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest difference I have found in FullCalendar is the JSON source payload dataset size. Making sure the JSON is delivery quick database call, use compression gzip/inflating at the server configuration is supported and only return the data that will be used. Many people return the entire select dataset if fields are not utilized.

For consecutive calls to fetch the data. I believe you are looking for refetchEvents() which can be used at any time after a callback function or when your looking to refresh the data. And only returned the needed date range on a given view. I only return week by week in the week view for example, not the entire month.

[Calendar::refetchEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents)

So for example, after completing the drag and drop callback event function you mention. This will only update the data elements and not the entire calendar in DOM.